# Tensorflow - single placeholder or list of them

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

i'm working in a code using Tensorflow,  and i came to this problem. the neural network i have to model, has many inputs ( lets say something like a image 512x512 ) annd those inputs are connected to other neurons in the network ( in a feedforward architecture ) , i have to test many of these networks and in each case the connections between  de input neurons and the other neurons is different.

So far i have done this by creating a placeholder( one dimensional)  for each input, store them in a python list, and save in a graph structure the relationships between neurons, but i'm concerned about performance, considering that in each training try, i will have to create something like 100 or more networks. So i end up with 512x512x100 placeholder objects. i'm wondering if i'll have memory issues,  in that case, running the code in Amazon Web Services or Google Cloud may help?

So i'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. maybe a way to create a single placeholder object for each network, and access the components in a "array like" way. but so far, i can't figure it out.

Any advise in how to approach this, is welcome :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to train all those 100 networks in parallel? Or what do you mean exactly by "training try"?

Comment: Tf is optimized for handling large tensors so prefer to have few large placeholder s instead of many small ones

Comment: Hi. @kaufmanu My approach it's a evolutionary neural net. so i need to keep in memory many nets and test them each generation. if is prefered to have a large tensor, how can i do it? if as i say, the connections between neurons are changing over time

Comment: Have a large input placeholder, and perfom over it slice operations may be a solution?